# How to add search box with icon in custom wordpress theme without plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i am new to wordpress . I have developed a theme in wordpress where in header.php i want to add a search box with navigation bar . 
I have tried alot but not able to add search box with icon in header.php of my developed custom theme of wordpress.

please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download Font-Awesome fonts and stylesheet from [here](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) and then use the class you need for the specific icon :)
You'll find more instructions on their site.

EDIT1

1. in header section try to add

   ```
   get_search_form ()
   ```

2.add the following code to your searchform.php file (or create if you don't have one)

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div>
<input type="text" size="18" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: i am asking for code for seachbox with icon , from above link i am not able to find for seachbox